# C# Linq to SQL: The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am writing a join query on linq to SQL. I am getting error on join keyword that "Error    14  The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'." Could you please help me? Let me know if anything else needed.

```
var query = (from fd in dbcDefaulter.Fees_Dues
                         join sd in dbcDefaulter.Student_Details on fd.Student_ID equals sd.Student_ID
                         orderby fd.Student_ID
                         select new {  fd.Month }).ToList();
```

Comment: What datatype is `Student_Details.Student_ID` ? What type is `Fees_Dues.Student_ID`? I'm guessing one's a numeric type and the other is a string type.

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. I am checking and update you asap.

Comment: Exactly `Student_Details.Student_ID.Student_ID is int` type whereas the other is nvarchar. Could you please tell me how to typecase them here?

Comment: I have used `Convert.ToInt32(fd.Student_ID)` for typecase is it okay? It is not giving any error now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you cast the id that is an `int` to a `string` before comparing?

```
var query = (from  fd in dbcDefaulter.Fees_Dues
                 join sd in dbcDefaulter.Student_Details 
                 on fd.Student_ID.ToString() equals sd.Student_ID
                 orderby fd.Student_ID
                 select new {  fd.Month }).ToList();
```

Comment: You could also try doing Convert.ToInt32 on the other (nvarchar) Id, but that could throw an exception, whereas ToString() will not.